# Gui won't start start dist-upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, gui

I did a fresh install, set up everything all day yesterday, did a dist-upgrade and autoremove, boom. Tried to reinstall desktop, no luck... Any help please?

[some package mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOi0e.jpg)

[gui not starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8As8.jpg)

Comment: Pictures of text on a screen is much harder to read than text placed in your question, but you've no doubt added some 3rd party package to your system to is conflicting with your desktop package thus the problem.  (*You've given few details; and I can't copy from a picture (unlike text in a question) thus can't easily do some searching of potential issues; though I suspect the problem relates to installs prior to your `apt autoremove`*)

Comment: I did check for held packages. There are none. So the link didn't help me. Only other source I added is multiverse. I would've copied text but how am I supposed to if I have no access to it?

Comment: You took a photo of the text, thus can login. You can pastebin the text from terminal, copy it to a file & send the file somewhere, or login remotely (`ssh` or a text login) & then use another system to copy & paste with a GUI tool if you're not familiar with terminal commands. There are many ways; but I'd ask whomever took for the photo you pasted as they do have access to the text.

Comment: Nvm, I had to downgrade libgbm1 to 22.04.1 since the dependencies are not yet available in the latest version apparently. Instead of complaining about the format other people actually tried to help me.

Answer (score -1):

I had to downgrade libgbm1 to 22.04.1 since some packages aren't available in 22.04.2 yet apparently. Reddit helped me far more than people here.

Comment: `libgbm1 | 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 | jammy-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` is the correct 22.04.2 package currently; there is `libgbm1 | 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2 | jammy-proposed  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` in proposed; but you shouldn't need that yet; if you do you have a sources or 3rd party package issue from earlier.